# Is it possible to bind an input of type date to a C# property of type string in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, .net-7.0

In a .NET 7.0 MVC project, I wonder if it's possible to get the value of an input of type `date`, like 04/26/2023, directly into a property of type `string`, like "04/26/2023".

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="date" name="StringDate" />
```

**C#**

```
public string StringDate { get; set; }
```

Or maybe even directly in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyAction(string StringDate)
{
    //Some logic
}
```

I want to make users select a date in an input of type `date` so they don't need to type it, but need the value as a `string`. I know I could make the input as type `text` and put a mask or datepicker on it, or get the date in C# and apply `ToString()` or `ToShortDateString()` to it. Was just wondering if there is a way of doing it directly from the input to the property.

Comment: Main question: why would you want a string? Specific types exist for a reason

Comment: Format would be culture depending so rather be explicit and do the date to string conversion explicitly with the culture/format you need/expect.

Comment: @riffnl I need a string to transfer the value to an XML. I know how to do this, was just curious about the posssibility of doing this binding directly

Comment: @Ralf The format is not important here, it's ok if I get the string in another format. Just wondering if the input value could go directly into a string variable or property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of "solved" it by using a `readonly` property to format the `DateTime` property that is bound to the view. Something like this:

**Model:**

```csharp
public class MyModel
{
    //Property used to bind the HTML input
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    //Read only property to always access the date as string
    public string StringDate => Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); //Just one example, but a lot of other things can be done here
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="date" name="Date" />
```

**Controller Action:**

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    //...

    //Reading the formatted date...
    var formattedDate = model.StringDate;

    //...
}
```

Anyway, it is not a direct bind from the HTML date input to a string property in the model, but it was the easiest way I found, and now I actually think this solution is kind of good and simple.